# Installing 2009 events code in Tridion 2011

Tags: 2009, event-system

We recently upgraded a Tridion 2009 site to 2011, and are now trying to migrate the events code. Unfortunately Tridion doesn't seem to be hooking into the events.

I've done the following:

- Update the event triggers in the MMC snap-in.
- Deployed the events DLL to the 2011 server and registered it using *regasm.exe*.

Have I missed any steps out? I've written plenty of 2011 extensions but am not that familiar with how the 2009 events system works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Legacy events are backwards compatible in Tridion 2011.

- Check if you class is using this Prog Id "TDSEvents.Events"
- Is your class COM visible?, you can check it in the AssemblyInfo class
- Does your assembly have an strong name?

As Nuno always recommends, after you have checked all the steps above, create a single vbs file and try to create an object for your class.

```
Set obj = CreateObject("TDSEvents.Events")
```

If the object is not null, then your are good.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Also, you may have to install the "LegacyEventAdapter" extension from Tridion world for events triggered by the Publisher service.

Comment: But in any case it is a lot better to just rewrite the code of your VB Event System and create a .Net one, the Legacy Event Adapter was just created to allow for quick upgrades when 2011 was just released, you should really consider not using it.